# Can't enable File Sharing under OSX Lion

Tags: macos, file-sharing

So I've upgraded to Lion, but now I can't enable **File Sharing**, when I press the checkbox, it simple shows the "correct" symbol and in less than half of a second it removes it again.

This happens the same for the 2 checkboxes under the *Options...* as well.

What can I do to enable File Sharing again?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd check the Console application (it is in the Applications/Utilities folder) and see what happens when you check the box. You'll get the full readout there. Update your post with the console messages if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out it's not only me, but following this [amazing tutorial](http://www.johnlarge.co.uk/2011/07/19/osx-lion-samba-smb-shares-broken-xbmc-not-working/) everything whent smooth and worked out nicely...

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict itself. The article you link says to disable the built in sharing - yet you show it enabled in the picture in the answer. I can see using macports to compile your own smb sharing program might work, but either the article is partly wrong or you have some extra steps to get the ports smb connected to the sharing preference pane. Could you edit/elaborate on your solution so others can make use of it?

Comment: it was only to let users know that it stays on, before, when you click it automatically unchecked no given us that ability, the article is correct, the image was only to let know, that it fixes :)

Comment: You're right - it was just me that was confused. You did mention it would click and then revert. Thanks for the clarification!